# C#: Supporting multiple types of databases with Table Adapters

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

Here's the scenario:

I want to be able to support both SQL Server CE and SQL Server 200x databases using a strongly-typed dataset.

The problem I'm getting is that it's compiling using a specific type of connection (either a SqlConnection or a SqlCeConnection) so I can't change the type at runtime to any IDbConnection object.

Am I asking too much from the Visual Studio-generated datasets?  If not, what's the trick to getting it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up using designer-generated TableAdapters a long time ago. There's not easy way to control what they do, no easy way to change the connection string for all of them... and of course, no way at all of make them work with different ADO.NET provider, since the provider is hard-coded in the generated code. TableAdapters don't even inherit a common base class so you can write generic code  (well, they do inherit from component, but that's pretty useless...)

Instead, I use my own homemade "TableAdapter" generator. It builds a `DbDataAdapter` from a SELECT query, using a `DbCommandBuilder` (actually, the SELECT query is not even necessary since it can be inferred from the `DataTable`'s structure). For more complex `DataTables` which need specific logic, I make them implement a custom `IDataAdapterProvider` so that they can provide their own `DbCommands`.

Comment: I figured it was getting to be the time to graduate to a better solution...  The lack of a common base class has annoyed me for a long time.

Comment: TableAdapters are declared as partials. You can implement an Interface on TableAdapters :)

Comment: Yes, good point... But they can't inherit from DbDataAdapter since they already inherits from Component